# Hiring a builder in X4

Tags: x4-foundations

I have gotten to the part in the questline where

> the player unlocks the station in Grand Exchange 1

and I can't find a builder on any main station, wharf, or shipyard, I haven't spotted any mammoth ships. Where should I look to hire one and how can I find one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have vision on a builder ship to hire. So either via satellites or your own ships. Sometimes it's hard to find one and sometimes they are all over.

If you go into the construction menu and click on the button to assign a builder you will get to the map with a filter on construction ships. That way you can search for ships. In that mode you can zoom out and maybe you see some free ships. But they may be far away and need some time to reach your station